# Javascript object with methods

Tags: javascript

How would I make an object, that I can instruct what to do, at certain points. See example:

```
function bar(){
    // call/execute the start() code
    // do something
    // do some other thing
    // do something else
    // call/execute the end() code
}



foo=new bar();
foo()
.start(function(param){
    console.log("start");
})
.end(function(param){
    console.log("end");
})
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't have classes; so it's completely not clear what you are asking.  in your example `bar()` is a function - you don't invoke it through `new()`. Maybe you want to switch to TypeScript instead. you will get classes *and* lifecycle events

Comment: @Felix: JS has classes and more generally constructors that are invoked via `new`.

Answer (score 1):

You could take some prototype functions and return instaead of an implicit `this`, a dunction with a bound `this`.

The functions use a fluent interface and returns `this`.

```js
function Bar() {
    return function() {
        return this;
    }.bind(this);
}

Bar.prototype.start = function (fn) { fn(); return this; };
Bar.prototype.end = function (fn) { fn(); return this; };

var foo = new Bar();

foo()
    .start(function(param) {
        console.log("start");
    })
    .end(function(param) {
        console.log("end");
    })
```

Comment: thank you Nina. the code within start() and end() code should be called from within Bar() at different points / scenarios. how do i actually call/execute them?

Comment: you can not have both, a standard instance with returning `this` and a funcction which returns `this`. only one of both works. maybe you add what you want in which cases.

Answer (score 1):

To chain function you need to return `this` or `object` itself you can try something like this

- Here `new bar()` will return a function, `foo()` will return the obj,
- On further `start` and `end` method call we update the property and return reference to object itself

```js
function bar() {
  let obj = {
    value: [],
    start(func) {
      this.value.push('start')
      console.log(this.value)
      func()
      return this
    },
    end(func) {
      this.value.push('end')
      console.log(this.value)
      func()
      return this
    }
  }
  return () => obj
}



foo = new bar();
foo()
  .start(function(param) {
    console.log("start");
  })
  .end(function(param) {
    console.log("end");
  })
```

Comment: Thank you. The code in .start() and .end() is just instructions, that would be executed from and by the code within bar function at different scenarios. say in bar() there was a line saying if(1==1){fire off the code within end() };